# Using Qt with eclipse, #include <QSqlDatabase> leads to file not found

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, include, qmake

So I have started a new Qt console project;

everything so far has been working fine. I have eclipse set up with the integration, but i'm not actually using it, i have just included the relevant Qt directories so that my `#include <QtGui>` calls work.

These have all worked perfectly so far.

i can compile it either using eclipse's build option, or by doing

```
qmake -project
qmake
make
```

from the command line. Both work.

the include statements i have; are:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>
```

In two different files.

If i add anotherone though, i.e. `#include <QSqlDatabase>` then eclipse recognises the include, and lets me initialise new variables, and use the QSqlDatabase classes. Everything seems fine - [see here - eclipse screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8pmV.jpg)

When i build the project though, it decides it can't see the files [even though they are all there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evV5I.jpg), [see them here in the terminal too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXk9s.jpg). And then [eclipse puts red lines everywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOvHm.jpg).

If i go into the directory, and attempt to do it all via the terminal, using the `qmake -project; qmake; make` then i get the same errors.

If however, I go into the `.pro` file created by `qmake -project`, and add the line `QT += sql`, and then do `qmake; make`, then all is fine and it works.

Why is `qmake -project` leaving out these files from the project file? I'd really rather not have to go in and manually add that line every time I build it...

Comment: Maybe its a copy/paste error, but you put `#include <QSqldatabase>` in the question and it should be QSqlDatabase, capitol D.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but sounds like its a linking problem and not compilation. For some reason its not detecting that it needs to link in the sql lib.

Comment: @Brady yah it was just a cut and paste error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is qmake -project leaving out these files from the project file?

As far as I know, qmake isn't supposed to replace human programmer. If you want to know WHY it doesn't detect SQL dependency, you can read qmake source code.

> I'd really rather not have to go in and manually add that line every time I build it...

It sounds like you're trying to do something weird here. You don't need to call qmake -project before every build.

`qmake -project` generates **initial** project - *pro file. Once initial project has been generated, you can tweak it, and add options or some macro magic if you want. Then, using *.pro file, you generate script for your build system (vcproj for windows, makefiles for windows/*nix, nmake make files, etc).

Workflow goes like this:

1. `qmake -project`.
2. Repeat forever:
   2.1. modify generated *.pro file to your liking.
   2.2 `qmake`
   2.3 Build using your build system. (nmake, make, visual studio, etc.)

To simply "build" all you have to do is #2.3. You call `qmake` (without -project) switch only if you modified *.pro file.

See qt [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/) and tutorials for more info.

Comment: I shall try this, hopefully all will go swimmingly.